# Python 3.6 - Accessing what key a number is

Tags: python, pygame, key

I have been making a game using pygame, in which a user can customize their controls. I want to be able to tell the user which key they have set to each variable, however, I am not sure how do do this, as when setting the variable I use `int(event.key)`, which returns the number of that key, which works fine. I want to be able to use this number and tell the user which key corresponds to that number.  I have in mind something that is like `print(key(number))`Thanks in advance!

Comment: All this information is in the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html). For example, `event.key` is already an integer, so `int(event.key)` isn't actually doing anything. That integer is just the unique ID of the key.

Comment: Thanks heaps! pygame.key.name(number) seems to work fine! I will work on implementing this now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I found the answer, `pygame.key.name(number)` works nicely! This returns values such as `space`, `up`, `down`, etc.